# Key Bindings on Page (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following question. I have a MainWindow, as well as several pages that switch through the MainWindowViewModel.

```
# MainWindwoViewModel.cs
private static MainWindowViewModel _instance;
        internal Page GamePage { get; private set; }
        internal Page MenuPage { get; private set; }
        internal Page SettingsPage { get; private set; }
        internal Page EndGamePage { get; private set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel(Page endGamePage, Page gamePage, Page menuPage)
        {
            _currentPage = menuPage;
            GamePage = gamePage;
            MenuPage = menuPage;
            EndGamePage = endGamePage;
            _instance = this;
        }

        private Page _currentPage;
        public Page CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPage;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentPage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public static MainWindowViewModel GetInstance() => _instance;
```

On one of the pages, you need to make a WASD keystroke event.

```
# GamePage.xaml
    <Page.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="W" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}"/>
    </Page.InputBindings>
```

But if you write this code in the page itself, then nothing happens. I solved this problem with the following crutch (as it seems to me).

```
# MainWindow.xaml
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="W" Command="{Binding GamePageCommand}" CommandParameter="w"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="A" Command="{Binding GamePageCommand}" CommandParameter="a"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="S" Command="{Binding GamePageCommand}" CommandParameter="s"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="D" Command="{Binding GamePageCommand}" CommandParameter="d"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>

#MainWindowViewModel.cs
public ICommand GamePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand((_) =>
                {
                    MainWindowViewModel viewModel = GetInstance();
                    if (viewModel.CurrentPage == viewModel.GamePage)
                    {
                        GamePageViewModel gameViewModel = (GamePageViewModel)viewModel.GamePage.DataContext;
                        gameViewModel.MoveCommand.Execute(_);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to do without it?

Comment: Can I see the source code of 'gamePageViewModel'?

Comment: Your page is not doing anything with the keystroke either because Keyboard focus is not within it OR keyboard focus is within it but whatever has that focus is already processing the keystroke.  Odds are it's the former, not the latter

Comment: RuleOfThumb: Whenever your `ViewModel` references a UI type (here `Page`) you did something wrong regarding MVVM